# JS/JSON - Parsing values of "data-original-title" in HTML to console log

Tags: javascript, userscripts

I was playing around with UserScript examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53044013/tampermonkey-userscript-to-get-table-cell-data-by-keyword-search) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33716712/how-to-grab-html-table-content-with-javascript) to try and find a close example of what Im looking for.

Sometimes the page has a table with 100s of entries, and I'd like to return the values of "data-original-title" all to a place where I can copy them, like a console log.

I tried the above scripts but couldn't target the label as expected.

Edit:
I guess I should clarify my request a little bit. Here's the full outerHTML

```
<td class="sorting_1">Lorem Ipsum<br><span class="label label-warning tooltip-class" title="ABC">ABC</span> <span class="label label-theme" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Source: http://ThisIsTheLinkNeeded.com">S</span> </td>

<td class="sorting_1">Dolar Emet<br><span class="label label-warning tooltip-class" title="ABC">ABC</span> <span class="label label-theme" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Source: http://ThisIsThe2ndLinkNeeded.com">S</span> </td>
```

It would be great for the console log to show:

Lorem Ipsum

http://ThisIsTheLinkNeeded.com

Dolar Emet

http://ThisIsThe2ndLinkNeeded.com

My attempt at a UserScript based on suggestion below which only returns values once they've been hovered on.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Parse Source Links Test
// @description hello
// @version 0.1
// @match    https://example.url/*
// @require  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// @grant    GM.getValue
// ==/UserScript==
//- The @grant directives are needed to restore the proper sandbox.
/* global $ */

let labels = document.querySelectorAll(".label.label-theme");
for (let label of labels) {
    console.log(label.dataset.originalTitle)
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with parsing JSON? That attribute is a plain string, not JSON.

Comment: Use `element.dataset.originalTitle` to get the value of that attribute.

Comment: What do either of those linked questions have to do with this?

Comment: I saw the previous questions tagged with JavaScript and another one with JSON - sorry if I mistagged, fixed!

Comment: Instead of adding some random `@grant`s to enable sandbox, use [`// @unwrap`](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#meta:unwrap).